# Log all method calls to a Java object from Clojure

Tags: java, debugging, reflection, clojure

I'm working on a Clojure wrapper for some Java library. 
In order to help me debug, I would like to log all calls to specific Java objects.

After searching how I might do this from a raw Java perspective, I discovered the `java.lang.reflect.Proxy` class and `java.lang.reflect.InvocationHandler` interfaces.

This led me to find [a small snipped posted by R.H. a few years ago](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/clojure/dsItNNpz_o0) :

```
(defn debug-proxy [obj] 
  (java.lang.reflect.Proxy/newProxyInstance 
    (.. obj getClass getClassLoader) 
    (.. obj getClass getInterfaces) 
    (proxy [java.lang.reflect.InvocationHandler] [] 
      (invoke [proxy m args] 
        (apply println m args) 
        (.invoke m obj args)))))
```

Small note: I had to change `java.lang.reflect.Proxy.newProxyInstance` into `java.lang.reflect/newProxyInstance` to make it work in my REPL, since `newProxyInstance` is a static method. Corrected version is given so that you may cut & paste it.

With this version, calling methods on the proxy appear work at first :

```
youpi.core=> (.charAt (debug-proxy "foo") 2) 
#object[java.lang.reflect.Method 0x53ce1eb0 public abstract char java.lang.CharSequence.charAt(int)] 2
=> \o
```

But sadly, **calling a method that accepts no argument will not work**:

```
youpi.core=> (.toUpperCase (debug-proxy "foo"))

IllegalArgumentException No matching field found: toUpperCase for class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1  clojure.lang.Reflector.getInstanceField (Reflector.java:271)

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No matching field found: toUpperCase for class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1
    at clojure.lang.Reflector.getInstanceField(Reflector.java:271)
    at clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeNoArgInstanceMember(Reflector.java:315)
    at youpi.core$eval5981.invokeStatic(form-init3685547971046661105.clj:1)
    at youpi.core$eval5981.invoke(form-init3685547971046661105.clj:1)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6927)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6890)
    at clojure.core$eval.invokeStatic(core.clj:3105)
    at clojure.core$eval.invoke(core.clj:3101)
    at clojure.main$repl$read_eval_print__7408$fn__7411.invoke(main.clj:240)
    at clojure.main$repl$read_eval_print__7408.invoke(main.clj:240)
    <...>
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I tried to update the invoke implementation following advice given in [this clojuredocs comment](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/proxy#example-542692d4c026201cdc327041), but it didn't fix.

Here is my (still broken) attempt at implementing the comment's suggestion:

```
(defn- debug-print-invoke [obj proxy m args]
  (apply println m args)
  (.invoke m obj args))

(defn debug-proxy [obj]
  (java.lang.reflect.Proxy/newProxyInstance
    (.. obj getClass getClassLoader)
    (.. obj getClass getInterfaces)
    (proxy [java.lang.reflect.InvocationHandler] []
      (invoke
        ([proxy m] (debug-print-invoke obj proxy m []))
        ([proxy m args] (debug-print-invoke obj proxy m args))))))
```

A good answer would either fix the snippet I've been working with, or suggest an alternative way to achieve the same goal from Clojure.

Comment: This could probably be achieved fairly easily through *byte code manipulation*.  There's a bunch of tools that can help with this, but never used any enough to make a recommedation

Comment: Dynamic proxies in Java work with interfaces not classes. In your example, calling `charAt` is fine because it is a call to a method of the `CharSequence` interface implemented by your proxy. Calling `toUpperCase` on the other hand won’t work because `toUpperCase` is a method on the class `String`, which is not implemented (so to speak) by your proxy.

Comment: @glts if I understand you correctly, using this approach will only let log calls to methods implemented as part of an Interface contract. Method arity is irrelevant, `(.length (debug-proxy "foo"))` works indeed properly.

Comment: @EliZor Yes. This is a limitation of dynamic proxies, if you want to proxy classes you will indeed have to drop down to the bytecode level I believe.

Comment: For what it's worth, I've manually written a bunch of proxy functions in a Clojure namespace, then used `clojure.tools.trace` to work on my immediate concerns. I'm still interested in a more elegant approach.